# Does bootstrapping artificially create significance?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, p-value, biostatistics

I'm trying to calculate a p-value for two samples and am having some issues understanding the role bootstrapping might play.

The data I have comes from an MRMC study: Five readers took a five-hundred question test creating five accuracy scores to form sample 1. Some time later, the same five readers took the same test, but this time with a suggested answer list. The five accuracy scores on the test the second time form sample 2.

My understanding is that a paired t-test would be the way to evaluate if the difference in average accuracy between the two conditions was significant or not. (Although I have heard that perhaps doing something like a repeated measures ANOVA might be better?)enter code here

My question is that sample 1 and sample 2 only give me 1 value for difference in average accuracy. I could bootstrap with replacement to get more samples, but this seems like it would artificially create significance? For example, if I bootstrapped 10M times over the data I have the average difference of these paired samples would be pretty much the difference in the average of sample 1 and sample 2.

Is there a best practice for using bootstrapping with the paired t-test or should I be looking to use some other methodology entirely?

Comment: Could you post the 5x2 data? Do you also have access to the question-level data?

Comment: You could also consider the exact Fisher-Pitman test for paired data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bootstrapping done properly will not inflate your metrics. Bootstrapping allows you obtain the estimate of the probability distribution of the test statistic. Getting the p-values from this distribution involves using the actual sample size.

Here's an example of incorrect application of bootstrapping. A scientist was asked to obtain 99.9th quantile of the distribution represented by 25 observations. A sample is too small, he figures, and fits a parametric distribution to the data, then samples 1 million observations from the estimated distribution to comfortably obtain the requested quantile. Don't do it like this.

*One way* to do this right would be to fit the same parametric distribution to the same 25 points and obtain its parameters $\hat\theta$, then produce 1 million samples of 25 random values from the distribution. Next, you fit the same parametric distribution to each of these samples, and estimate parametrically 99.9th quantiles $\hat q_i$, and with 1 million readings you can build the distribution of the quantile estimate. You can now estimate its mean and confidence intervals, with latter most likely being very wide to indicate what we already should have known: 25 observations will not produce useful estimate of 99.9th quantile in most cases. In your words "this procedure will not inflate significance", in this example it is likely to reveal the unreasonableness of the ask.

Again, this was just one way of doing this correctly. You can look up the design of Lilliefors test, a variation of widely applied K-S test, to see how it's done right for a particular problem at hand.

Comment: To clarify -- bootstrapping just involves sampling with replacement, or is there something else to be wary of? And How would one calculate the paired t-test with bootstrapping and have the degree of freedom be the initial sample size. The implementations I've seen automatically calculate degrees of freedom from the length of the arrays passed (i.e. the number of samples in the bootstrapped array).

Comment: The question was not about CIs for parameter estimates, but for a non-parametric Monte Carlo test in analogy to the paired t-test. For this particular case, permutation tests are the appropriate approach, AFAIK: In other words: drawing *without* replacement, not *with* replacement as for the bootstrap.

Comment: Nicely done.  Clear.  Succinct.  Comprehensible.  Thank you. Is the following a fair version of Lilliefors that you were suggesting? https://bookdown.org/egarpor/NP-UC3M/nptests-dist.html

Answer (score 2):

First note that a bootstrap sample (draws with replacement) must contain exactly the same number of observations (independent draws) like the original data. I wonder however how bootstrap could be useful in this case.

As an alternative to the parametric paired t-test, there is a Monte Carlo test, but it is not based on bootstrapping, but on label permutations. The idea is to simulate the distribution under the null hypothesis by randomly flipping group labels*) in your pairs, doing this $B$ times and compute the test statistic $t_b$ for each. The p-value is then the percentage of $|t_b|$ that is greater than the observed value for $|t|$ in the original sample.

According to Racine & MacKinnon ("Simulation-based Tests that can Use Any Number of Simulations", 2004), this method has an exact type I error $\alpha$ if $B$ is chosen such that $\alpha(B-1)$ is an integer.

*) But in such a way that the total number of positive and negative signs is not changed. IOW: randomly select a permutation of the signs of the difference.

**Edit:** I had copied the constrained that the number of positive and negative signs be constant from a description of this test (see the comments below), but it does not make sense (consider the extreme case of all signs identical). It is thus better to randomly flip signs, which is equivalent to randomly flipping group labels.

Comment: What does it mean to flip group labels for paired data? Is it swapping the treated and untreated scores for each person?

Comment: Flipping labels is the same as flipping the sign of the difference. More formally, proceed as follows: 1) list all signs. 2) randomly permute the signs (draw **without** replacement) 3) compute the mean with the permuted signs. An internet search form "paired t test monte carlo" or "permutation test paired" should yield more formal descriptions.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. Two more questions. With just 5 observations, wouldn’t using the exact 2^5 permutations be easier than sampling? Why do you need the constraint from the footnote?

Comment: Concerning the footnote: good quastion! I had copied this constrained from https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/NCSS/Paired_T-Test.pdf, but I on a second thought it does not seem to make sense: when all signs are positive, no sign will be flipped and this is definitely not compatible with the null hypothesis. It makes more sense to randomly assign signs. And if you only have five observations, an effect must be *very* strong to be statistically significant.